# Security risks when using an encrypted container to share messages

Tags: encryption, email, veracrypt

If I use VeraCrypt and create a container with a strong 64 character password and key files stored on a USB that's locked away, using the container, can I securely send e-mail?

I'm aware I could use a mail client, such as Thunderbird and OpenPGP, but suppose if I wanted to use an encrypted container, from what I can see, the threats are:

- I would have to securely exchange the keys and password with any recipients  this can potentially be difficult if the recipient is international.
- How the keys and password are stored by the recipients? Even if I take precautions and store the password and keys securely, this doesn't mean the recipient are doing the same.
- You would have to be aware of what risks exist for Veracrypt and defend yourself against them, if that's possible.

I'm no expert, so are there any other risks that I don't see?

Comment: It sounds like your main concern is confidentiality of the files, rather than authentication (verifying via a cryptographic signature that the sender is who you expect).  In this case sending a container would protect the confidentiality, assuming you used a sufficiently random and unique password, and succeeded to transfer the password out of band without it being intercepted.  Maybe if you explained why you want to use a container rather than OpenGPG that would help.

Comment: @Daisetsu This isn't necessarily true. Confidentiality is violated if the same container is shared twice in between modifications due to quirks in the way XTS (the mode of operation VeraCrypt uses) works.

Comment: @Daisetsu - There is no real reason why, it's just something that crossed my mind.

Comment: @forest I did a bit of googling, but didn't immediately find anything related to XTS and modifications. Is there a question about that already?  If not I'll post a new one and you can answer it.

Comment: @Daisetsu https://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/04/30/you-dont-want-xts/